# cannot update from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: apt

I have been trying to update from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 for several days.  Whenever I try to run the upgrade, I get the following message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The update then terminates.
Is there any work around to this?

Comment: I suggest you read through this question to update the software sources as 13.04 [went EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) -  [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release). If you want to update to a supported release, I would suggest a fresh install of 14.04

Answer (score 0):

These errors are coming because Ubuntu has stopped support for 13.04. 
It is preferable you download and install the new and more secure 14.04 LTS(Long Term Support) version which will be in support for long. 
 But if you have update to 13.04 as your only option then you change your software sources to a server where files are still present.

For that you do the following:-

1. Open Ubuntu Software Center
2. Goto Edit -> Software Sources -> Ubuntu Software Tab
3. Click the drop-down showing "Main Server"
4. Select Other.
5. Goto **India** -> choose **ftp.iitb.ac.in**
6. Give Password if asked.


   Retry your update.

Comment: I tried this, and any attempt to change the server does not save.  Not sure why.  I'll have to go with the fresh install.  I was just hoping there woul dbe another way.